# No rows found in update scripts when trying to update a inserted record on the same ReadCommitted Transaction in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-2016

I'm using **C# 4.0** and **SQL server 2016**. Also using **ADO.Net** Inline query to insert and update details.

Here is the sample code i am using:

```
TransactionOptions txOpt = new System.Transactions.TransactionOptions();
txOpt.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, txOpt))
{
    int uniqueValue =  InsertRecordInDB("Hi","Hello"); //returns 1
    UpdateRecordInDB(uniqueValue,"Bye"); // sometimes update return no row found.
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Sometime the update method is returning no row found. Multiple calls will be made to this method at the same time from various users.

Am i missing something or is there any error in my code?

Comment: I am not experienced in posting question in  stack overflow. Kindly correct me if i have done some mistakes.

Comment: Take a look at the following link: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @M.Mohabbati Thanks. will do.